# Symfony 3.4 не грузит CSS и JS

Tags: javascript, css, symfony3, sonata

Не подгружаються стили и JS файлы, как в моем AppBundle так и в SanataAdminBundle. 
Файлы подключены через assets, прим :

```
<link   href="{{asset('bundles/app/css/bundle.css')}}">
<link   href="{{asset('bundles/app/css/hody-icons.css')}}">
<link   href="{{asset('bundles/app/css/style.css')}}">
```

Либо

```
<link  href="{{asset('bundles/app/css/bundle.css')}}">
<link  href="{{asset('bundles/app/css/hody-icons.css')}}">
<link  href="{{asset('bundles/app/css/style.css')}}">
```

Команды такие как:

- php bin/console assets:install --symlink web
- composer require symfony/assetic-bundle

Не помогли

Comment: что выдает php bin/console assets:install --symlink web? bundles папка появилась в web? если да, есть ли там bundles/app/css/bundle.cs

Comment: Выдает в конечном итоге:                                                                            
 [OK] All assets were successfully installed.                                   
Да, в Web есть папка bundles и в ней есть bundle.css по этому пути -    bundles/app/css/bundle.css